# Creating EVI from sentinel2 image using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sentinel-2, evi

I am trying to calculate EVI from sentinel2 image using ArcMap and I used the following equation

```
(2.5* (NIR/10000-red/10000))/(NIR/10000+(6*red/10000)- (7.5*blue/10000)+1)
```

but I get very weird result and not ranging from -1 to +1.

Can anyone help me on this issue?